# Is it possible to get ntpdate working behind a proxy?

Tags: linux, unix, proxy, ntp

ntpdate command seems to ignore http_proxy ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ntpdate uses **NTP** protocol, not HTTP.

**NTP uses UDP on port 123 as its transport layer**, while http uses TCP port (80 by default)

From *ntpdate man page*:

> ntpdate sets the local date and time by polling the
>      Network Time Protocol (NTP) server(s) given as the server arguments
>      to determine the correct time.

These are **totally unrelated protocols**. See wikipedia for a deeper explanation of **[Network Time Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol)**

Answer (score 0):

Try [HTTP Time Protocol](http://www.vervest.org/htp/).